# Add gradient layer to uiviewcontroller uiview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a simple gradient for the background of a UIViewController.  My code is:

```
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
    let bottomColor = UIColor(hue: 208 / 360, saturation: 82 / 100, brightness: 0.9, alpha: 1)
    let topColor = UIColor(hue: 208 / 360, saturation: 41 / 100, brightness: 0.9, alpha: 1)
    gradientLayer.colors = [bottomColor, topColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.1)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)

    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

The gradient does not show.  When I look in the view debugger, I do not see it.  I check the frame of the view and it looks ok

```
x: 0, y:0, width: 375, height: 667
```

I've tried the `view.layer.insert` at method as well, but that did not work.  If I do

```
view.layer.backgroundColor.orange
```

then I do see an orange background.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What method are you adding the gradient layer in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
gradientLayer.colors = [bottomColor, topColor]
```

to

```
gradientLayer.colors = [bottomColor.cgColor, topColor.cgColor]
```